# If scientists proved that there is life after death, would you rather die than remain alive?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

If scientists proved that there is life after death, would most people rather die than remain alive?

Comment: Why ? You are alive already.

Comment: I made an edit which I hope clarifies your intent.  If it does not please roll this back or edit it further.  If you have any book you are reading that suggests this question to you it may provide context and help someone trying to answer the question. Welcome!

Comment: You need more detail. What do we know about this life after death. Do we come back as humans? in what era? Is it chance as to what social status and geographical region you re-appear? Because i might consider suicide if I were to come back as beyonce, or giovani pernice.

Comment: I don't see how this question or the possible answers to it help anyone. But personally, no I like my life

Comment: this is the most opinion based question ever

Comment: Also, is it worth mentioning that if there is "life after death", then doesn't that render death meaningless? What would it even mean to die, other than just separating one point in life from another?

Comment: A lot of people believe you forfeit any chance of eternal life, if you commit murder (including suicide).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE.

The answer to this question is subjective because many people are enjoying their present life.  Then why should they commit suicide and end their life?  So the answer to the question depends on their present condition (their living condition, age, ailments, relation etc.)

Many philosophers have mentioned that this life is a continuation of a past life. If you try to analyze people's abilities, you can't disprove this.  See, they are not well-known scientists. The only thing you need is a keen power of observation and a keen power of analyzing. If so, if you believe the words of philosophers what would you do? From your question I believe you have stronger faith in scientists than in philosophers.  If scientists can't assure whether the next is human-life and it is here, most people never think about ending their life. So the people's decision depends on faith also.

Some innocent people might think: "How could I live again in this peaceless world suffering many difficulties?  So I should try my best to make this earth a good place for my next birth.  So I must live here as it is now as far as possible."

Comment: It also depends on the quality of the afterlife. E.g. if life after death is eternal and more blissful than anything you can experience here, then even the happiest person on Earth should want to end their life for the afterlife

Comment: @Bridgeburners: I have added that idea also.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe in an afterlife but I'd much rather stay here.